# Excel VBA - Apply sumif to only a specific coloured cell - referencing the above coloured cell

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I have a sheet with this format:

How can I make a macro that creates a SUMIF function (like `=SUMIF(K419:K421;">0")` ) in every grey cell in column K?

It should sum up the white cells directly above it until it reaches the next grey cell above. The number of white cells above each grey cell is inconsistent.

This is an example of the column K: white, white, grey, white, white, white, white, grey, white, grey.

Regarding the range of the sumif:
I know that R[-1] references the cell directly above each grey cell but how am I supposed to reference the cell directly after the above grey cell?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you do so far to solve your problem?

Comment: No concrete code, I just had the idea to use an if function along the lines of "if grey cell, then apply the formula with the above stated range" Im not sure how to formulate the above-stated range in the "then" part and also how to reference all grey cells in the "if" part

Comment: How are the grey cells set to grey?  Are you doing this in code?  If so, then can't you just add your sum function when you set the cell color?  If it is not set this way, then are we to assume the white cells have values and the grey cells do not?

Comment: The cells are already coloured in the spreadsheet. Yes, white cells have a number value and grey cells are empty and should sum up the above number values.

Comment: Have you tried any vba code in the past 3 hours to try to solve this?  If so, post it and we can show you where you are going wrong.

Comment: `Sub biggest()   Large = 0 For Each theCell In Range("E2:E27")    If theCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then    theCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(R[-2]C:R[-1]C,"">0"")"    End If     Next    End Sub` - I need to replace the R[-2]C part with the reference to the above grey cell but I have no idea how to.

Comment: dont mind the variable names - theyre random at the moment. And sorry about the formatting. Also for this example I used 3 (red) but dont mind that.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to think about how you would do this manually.  i.e.

1) Start at top of Column K.

2) Move down column K until blank

3) Enter SUMIF Statement using range of last grey cell + 1 to current gray cell - 1

4) Loop until bottom of data

So...

```
Private Sub loopSumIF()
Dim currentRow As Integer
Dim lastGreyRow As Integer
Dim endLoop as Boolean

currentRow = 2
lastGreyRow = 2
endLoop = False

Do Until endLoop = True
    if ActiveSheet.Range("K" & currentrow) = "" then
        ActiveSheet.Range("K" & currentRow) = "=SUMIF(K" & lastGreyRow & ":K" & currentorw - 1 & "," & Chr(34) & ">0" & Chr(34) & ")" 'set formula
        lastGreyRow = currentRow + 1 'set the top of the next sumif to the next cell down
    End If
    currentRow = currentRow + 1 'move currentrow down
    If ActiveSheet.Range("K" & currentRow) = "" Then endLoop = True 'two blank cells in a row indicates end of data
Loop

End Sub
```

Note: You could do this by looking at the colorIndex of the cell instead, but if for some reason someone decides to use a slightly different shade of gray, or pink (as an example), then it will not work correctly.  You may be safer looking at blank values instead.

Comment: About colorindex - if not looking for a certain color, he can use for any different than white, it also should do the trick.

Comment: True, but then you have those end users who color-code _everything_ ;)

Comment: You can't please anyone ;) Anyway, from what I read it doesn't need functionality to other users, rather to himself. But normally, yeah it could be a problem - like whole humankind ;)

Comment: I like this solution, it doesnt explicitly mention the colour but works around it by using the fact that these cells are also empty. I havent got it to work yet but I can work with this! Thanks

Comment: For future reference: The problem was the end loop sequence, the script worked perfectly without it (with the small problem of an infinite loop :D) but didnt work when it was included, so I changed it to: If ActiveSheet.Range("K" & **lastGreyRow**) = "" Then endLoop = True